# Power Shell: Using variables when trying to add users to group

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I have been trying to find a way to bulk add users to a group from a variable.
I create my variables.
Test my variables.  And then when I use them, the system interprets them in a way I didn't expect.  Has anyone figured out how to best automate this process?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $user = get-MsolUser | Select ObjectID
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $user

ObjectId
--------
97232511-7ea5-4f26-9372-************
baa75007-e0fc-4265-b17c-************


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $group = get-MsolGroup -ObjectId 776da14a-9c10-4dd1-b880-************ | Select ObjectID
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $group

ObjectId
--------
776da14a-9c10-4dd1-b880-************


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Add-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectID $group -GroupMemberType User -GroupMemberObjectId $user
Add-MsolGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter 'GroupObjectId'. Cannot convert the "@{ObjectId=776da14a-9c10-4dd1-b880-d0646d49e926}"
value of type "Selected.Microsoft.Online.Administration.Group" to type "System.Guid".
At line:1 char:36
+ Add-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectID $group -GroupMemberType User -Grou ...
+                                    ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-MsolGroupMember],     ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.AddGroupMember

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this while selecting a group and then pass it to the `Add-MsolGroupMember`    cmdlet.

```
$group = get-MsolGroup -ObjectId 776da14a-9c10-4dd1-b880-************ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ObjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to answer provided.

```
$group = get-MsolGroup -ObjectId 776da14a-9c10-4dd1-b880-************

$users = get-MsolUser

foreach($user in $users){
    Add-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectID $group.objectId -GroupMemberType User -GroupMemberObjectId $user.objectId
}
```

Because you're returning multiple users you'll want to foreach them as the cmdlet only accepts one argument for the `-GroupMemberObjectId`. Also with your current set up getting the group is obsolete since you already know the object id you could achieve the same with.

$groupObjectId = "776da14a-9c10-4dd1-b880-************"

```
$users = get-MsolUser

foreach($user in $users){
    Add-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectID $groupObjectId  -GroupMemberType User -GroupMemberObjectId $user.objectId
}
```

Comment: If it works can you please select the most appropriate answer to help future users of StackOverflow to find answers :)